# Cant install PyNaCl with pip inside a PyCharm venv

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

Using python3.8.1, installing newest version, on Windows 10:

`pip install PyNaCl` gives me this error (last 10 lines):

```
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "setup.py", line 161, in run
      raise Exception("ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH")
  Exception: ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for PyNaCl
  Running setup.py clean for PyNaCl
Failed to build PyNaCl
Could not build wheels for PyNaCl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

It seems to be related to wheels, so i tried to install it with `no-binary`, which also failed:

```
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q0db5s_n\PyNaCl\setup.py", line 161, in run
        raise Exception("ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH")
    Exception: ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\DiscordBot\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q0db5s_n\\PyNaCl\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-s27dvlrv\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\DiscordBot\venv\include\site\python3.8\PyNaCl" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q0db5s_n\PyNaCl\
```

EDIT: This only seems to be an issue in my venv (made by Pycharm) - i have no clue what the issue is, both setuptools and wheel are installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ultimately solved it by using `python -m pip install --no-use-pep517 pynacl`

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading pip within the venv worked for me:

```
.\env\Scripts\activate
pip install -U pip
pip install -r requirements.txt
deactivate
```